# How can I call a click function no matter which button in a list is clicked with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a number of submit buttons in a loop that’s inside a BeginForm().  I’m using jquery like this:

```
   $('.submit').click(function () {
   mydropdown = $('#Category');

           if (mydropdown.length == 0 || $(mydropdown).val() == "") {
               alert("Please select an ‘a category’.");

               return false;


           }
 });
```

Is there a way to call the click function even if the user does not click on the first button in the list?

Comment: looks like the elements are created dynamically, so try [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) - `$(document).on('click', '.submit', function(){...})`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've already done it. Your selector will match any button in the list as long as they have the submit class

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="button 1" class="submit"/>
<input type="button" id="button2" value="button 2" class="submit"/>
<input type="button" id="button3" value="button 3" class="submit"/>

$('.submit').click(function () // will work for any button above
```

Alternatively if that is not working because the buttons have been added dynamically (ie after page load) then you need to use .on() instead of .click()

```
$(document).on('click', '.submit', function(
```

Comment: Yes buttons are added dynamically.  I tried  $(document).on('click', '.submit',function () {} but I must still be missing something...the page is still being submitted and ignoring the alert.